# "Const variables allow an object sub-properties to be changed but not the object structure"

Tags: javascript, constants

"Const variables allow an object sub-properties to be changed but not the object structure."

What means "object structure"?
Because this code is compiling:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]; // inferred to type number[]
numbers.push(4); // no error
```

May anyone give a compiling error of a sentence after declaring the const "numbers" in my example?

Comment: The sentence is wrong. The object structure sure can be changed. The restriction is that the variable name can't be reassigned to point to an altogether different object. `const someVarName = ...; someVarName = somethingElse` is forbidden, that's all

Comment: Oh ok, it calls "object structure" to REDEFINE the const.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, thanks I realized that after checking some examples.